# Finding Altitude in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, altitude

I've been having trouble finding a way to get the altitude of the device. Could someone give me a pointer or put together a short script that gets the altitude of the device and prints it? Only in swift. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the GPS altitude is very inaccurate. You may expect jumps of +/- 10m for the same location.

Comment: Good point, guess this isn't what I'm looking for then. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Import CoreLocation

```
import CoreLocation
```

Create a locationManger variable

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Initialize and start updating location

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
   var alt = newLocation.altitude
   println("\(alt)")
   manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist` otherwise the location services will not work on iOS 8.