# Mapkit - Get altitude

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit

Is there a way to get altitude, with mapkit, from given points from the map?
(Without being in spot).

For example touching the map, and getting altitude for touched map coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MapKit [doesn't provide](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8446) the altitude at a given point. You can only know the current altitude of the [camera](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapcamera) of a MKMapView, or the altitude of the [user position](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation). For your purpose, you can afford on  external web services like:

- [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro)
- [MapQuest API](https://developer.mapquest.com/products)